# Delete several people at once from a group conversation

Tags: skype, contacts

I need to delete several people from a Skype conversation group.

The context menu that appears when I select several people in a group and right-click on the selection doesn't contain an option to exclude those members. Neither do the following attempts of mine at using the `/kick` command work:

1. ```
   /kick name1 name2
   ```
2. ```
   /kick name1,name2
   ```
3. ```
   /kick name1;name2
   ```
4. ```
   /kick name1
   /kick name2
   ```

I know that I could remove them individually, either by right-clicking on a member and selecting *Remove person from this group* or by using `/kick`. However, if I do remove them one by one, all the remaining members get the notification, including those that I am going to remove as well, which I don't want.

Searching the Internet was to no avail.

So, does anybody know whether there actually is a way to exclude several group members in one go? And if so, how to do that?